# Прописная/строчная буква при перечислении названий граф

Tags: пунктуация, прописная-строчная

Нужно ли начинать слово внутри кавычек с заглавной?
Текст: ***Правильность подсчета по графам  — «Всего начислено», «К выдаче»...***

Answer (score 1):

Графа таблицы — это ряд данных, расположенный вертикально.

Заголовки граф и боковика пишутся в именительном падеже, **начинаются с прописной буквы**, в конце точка не ставится. Если головка таблицы многоярусная и заголовки нижележащих ярусов подчинены верхним, то со второго яруса допустима строчная буква в начале заголовка графы.
[Правила оформления таблиц](http://www.delo-press.ru/articles.php?n=25467)

Если названия граф в Вашей таблице начертаны с прописной (что чаще всего), то и в предложении, в котором они перечисляются, должны быть использованы прописные буквы.

> Правильность подсчета по графам — «**В**сего начислено», «**К** выдаче»...

Думаю, что можно использовать и курсив (но все равно — с прописной):
Правильность подсчета по графам — *Всего начислено*, *К выдаче*...

> Графы 18 «**Т**абельный номер» и 19 «**Т**арифная ставка (часовая, дневная)
>   (оклад), руб.» могут быть заполнены уже на этапе открытия табеля за месяц при
>   внесении общих сведений о работнике (["Учет рабочего времени"](https://specialitet.ru/lekcyi/kd/lekcyy_modul_6_vopros_1.PDF)).

Answer (score 0):

Нужно. Кинотеатр "Радуга". Роман "Война и мир", графа "К выдаче"

Comment: Подробного правила не хватает. Либо исключений